# Store an object inside another object

Tags: javascript, object, factory

I need to insert one object inside another, and I'm using this logic:

```
// Create object store
const store = {}

// Function to create 'Product' Objects
function createProduct (type, name, price) {
  return { type, name, price }
}

// Function to add 'Product' Objects inside the 'Store' Object
function addToStore (obj) {
  store.obj = obj
  return store
}

const strawberry = createProduct ('fruit', 'strawberry', '0.40')
const peach = createProduct ('fruit', 'peach', '0.80')

addToStore(strawberry)
addToStore(peach) 
console.log(store) // < { obj: { type: 'fruit', name: 'peach', price: '0.90' } }
```

How should I write this function so that store.obj be the same obj passed by parameter?

```
function addToStore (obj) {
  store.obj = obj
  return store

// What's happening in the run
function addToStore (peach) {
  store.obj = peach
  return store

// What I need to happen
function addToStore (peach) {
  store.peach = peach
  return store
```

Comment: Depends on what the expected result is. Currently, you’re overwriting the `obj` property.

Comment: Please give an example of the output _you actually want_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean that you want the property name to come from the name of the variable you use when calling `addToStore`, you can't *quite* do that, because when `addToStore` gets called, it just receives the *value* of that variable (the reference to the object), it doesn't receive any information about the variable itself.

The simple solution is to pass the name as a second argument:

```
function addToStore(name, obj) {
    store[name] = obj;
    return store;
}
// ...
addToStore("peach", peach);
```

Note the use of `[]` to make the property name come from the `name` parameter rather than using `.` with a literal name.

There is a way to make that a bit more automatic, at the (very small) cost of creating a temporary object, by using shorthand property syntax. Pass an object wrapper around the object you want, where the name of the property comes from the variable name, and have `addToStore` take the object from that wrapper (or perhaps take all of them, if you pass more than one):

```
function addToStore(objects) {
    Object.assign(store, objects); // Will do the loop and assignments for you
    return store;
}
// ...
addToStore({peach});
//         ^^^^^^^−−−−−−−−−−− creating the object to pass in using shorthand syntax
```

You probably wouldn't want to do that in code that's going to do it millions of times in an hour because of the overhead, but short of that I wouldn't worry about it until/unless you ran into a performance problem you tracked down to it.

Comment: Thank you a lot sir!